# Creating database replica in Access-VBA does not work

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, replication

I am trying to create a replica of a database:

```
Dim db as Database
Set db=DBEngine.Workspaces(0).OpenDatabase("h:\source.accdb")
db.MakeReplica "h:\replica.accdb", "TEST", dbRepMakeReadOnly
```

I always get the runtime error 3032 "Cannot perform this Operation" whenever the 3rd line runs. I do not have any idea why this happens.

As I understand, `MakeReplica` creates a "copy" of the source database and allows later synchronization using `db.Synchronize`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> As I understand, MakeReplica creates a "copy" of the source database
> and allows later synchronization using db.Synchronize.

Yes, but not using the accdb format. Only the "old" *mdb* format can be used, and the latest Access version to support replication is Access 2003.

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply. Then the only way seems to just simply copy the .accdb file to a "backup" folder and that is it.

Comment: If all you need is backup(s), that'l do. But it is "one way"; it's not the same as replication where you can modify any copy and the other will replicate the changes. You could also create a zip - that makes versioning a little easier and clearly indicates what is the master and which are the copies. You may study my project [VBA.Compress](https://github.com/GustavBrock/VBA.Compress) for code to easy creating zip and cab files.